# Weird JSONP response in Facebook

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I'm wondering what is the reason for using following JSONP response syntax:

Under URL: https://ect.channel.facebook.com/probe?mode=stream&format=json

There is:

```
for (;;); {"t":"heartbeat"}
{"t":"heartbeat"}
{"t":"continue","seq":0}
```

My question is, what exactly does `for(;;);` in this JSONP response. How is it parsed?

Comment: I see there is no function call, but the technique seems to be similar

Comment: No; the technique is exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't JSONP; it's JSON which is delibaretly modified to fail if used as JSONP.

If you include that URL in a `<script>` tag, it will freeze the browser in an infinte `for` loop.

This prevents attackers from including it in an external site and calling `Object.defineProperty` to create a setter function and bypass the SOP.

Answer (score 3):

That is there for security reasons.  JSONP is not *actually* JSON, it's a JavaScript file that's executed.

The `for(;;);` is there, so that if people (outside of Facebook) try to access that file, they can't.

NOTE: This isn't JSONP, but your browser doesn't know that.  It'll try to run it, then get stuck in an infinite loop.